# How to use ripcord in laravel

Tags: laravel, ripcord

I'm trying to use the ripcord library in Laravel 5.8, but I do not know what to make it work. I still do not understand how laravel works, so I do not know where some things fit.

This is the link from where I take the library:
https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/Ripcord

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Note: I have used the ripcord library with pure PHP.

I have only used the composer, I do not understand where to put the rest of the code to make it work.

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: Edit this question and add link to library

Answer (score 0):

From the repo, I can tell that you have to:

Install the package

```
composer require darkaonline/ripcord
```

Register the Service

Open your AppServiceProvider (located in app/Providers) and add this line in register function

```
$this->app->register(\Ripcord\Providers\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class);
```

Publish the config

```
php artisan ripcord:publish
```

Comment: Hi Tirta, I write in console: ´php artisan ripcord:publish´and then laravel return message: Method Ripcord\Providers\Laravel\Console\PublishCommand::handle() does not exist

Comment: Try add the service provider on config/app.php
\Ripcord\Providers\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class

Comment: @tirtakeniten The same error even after adding a service provider in config/app.php